# how to set a int32 value at some index within an m128i with only SSE2?

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics, sse2

Is there a SSE2 intrinsics that can set a single int32 value within m128i?

Such as set value 1000 at index 1 on a m128i that already contains 1,2,3,4? (which result in 1,1000,3,4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If SSE4 available, use

`__m128i _mm_insert_epi32 (__m128i a, int i, const int imm8)`

If you are limited to SSE2, you need to split it to two calls of

`__m128i _mm_insert_epi16 (__m128i a, int i, const int imm8)`

```
return _mm_insert_epi16(_mm_insert_epi16(a, 1000, 2), 0, 3);
```

to set 1000 on lane 1 of `a` interpreted as vector of ints.

With SSE3 available, I would presume that a shifting/shuffling sequence would be more efficient:

```
a = _mm_shuffle_epi32(a, 0xe0);      // shuffle as 3 2 0 ?
__m128i b = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(value);
b = _mm_alignr_epi8(b, a, 4);        // value 3 2 0
return  _mm_shuffle_epi32(b, 0x5c);  // 3 2 value 0
```

If the `value` is in a 64-bit register, one can use `_mm_cvtsi64_si128` instead.

Gcc is able to convert the store load sequence to `pinsrd xmm0, eax, 1` when SSE4 enabled, but gives quite a convoluted sequence without `-msse4`.

```
    movd    eax, xmm0
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24], xmm0
    movabs  rdx, 4294967296000
    or      rax, rdx
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-24], rax
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]
    ret
```

OTOH clang respects the store, modify stack, load paradigm.

```
    movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp - 24], xmm0
    mov     dword ptr [rsp - 20], 1000
    movaps  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsp - 24]
    ret
```

Probably the overall winner is the store/modify/load combo, which also has free programmable index. All others require hard coded immediates, including those using the insert intrinsics.

```
__m128i store_modify_load(__m128i a, int value, size_t index) {
   alignas(16) int32_t tmp[4] = {};
   _mm_store_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(tmp), a);
   tmp[index] = value;
   return  _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(tmp));
}
```

See the [produced assembly in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ecY6evbGh).

Comment: SSE2 or SSE3. Can you show me an example of "double" calls?

Comment: Intel Intrinsic Guide lists `_mm_insert_epi16` as SSE2.

Comment: Set the low 16-bit of int32 to index `j*2` and high 16-bit part to index `j*2+1`.

Comment: @markzzz: Note that 2x `pinsrw` is fairly inefficient, although in some cases still better than vector store / scalar store / vector reload (store forwarding stall) if you only have 1 element to replace.  Better if you can shuffle or blend a new 32-bit element into your vector another way.  e.g. with `movss` to replace the low element, or `shufps` or `punpcklqdq` or something if you want to replace a pair of elements (and optionally move existing ones around).

Comment: @PeterCordes can you give to me an example?

Comment: @markzzz: Of what, `_mm_store` / `_mm_load` to a local `alignas(16) int tmp[4]` and reloading?  Or of using `_mm_cvtsi32_si128(int)` + `_mm_move_ss(__m128, __m128)` with casts to keep the compiler happy?  It's pretty straightforward, and you can search by instruction mnemonic on the intrinsics guide to find intrinsics for any given instruction mnemonic.

Comment: @Aki: *I would presume that a shifting/shuffling sequence would be more efficient:* `pinsrw xmm, r32` costs about as much as `movd xmm, r32` + any shuffle (like `punpcklwd`), i.e. 2 uops for port 5 on modern CPUs, unfortunately.  Trading one of the movd operations for an extra shuffle actually increases the critical path latency from 2 to 3 cycles.  (uops.info measured pinsrw a 2 cycle latency from operand 1 -> 1, but they used only shuffles in the xmm dependency chain so competition for ports delayed the critical path even if the integer reg is ready early). You are saving an integer `shr` :/

Comment: (I'd suggest including your Godbolt link in your answer for other people to play with, unless you're trying to keep the store/reload example out of the hands of newbies :P)  Too bad about GCC; I guess that's because it defines `__m128i` as a vector of two `long long` elements, and that gets its optimizer all crossed up.  Looks like a mess.

Comment: Since you mention a 64-bit integer, that means you're replacing either the high or low half, which you can do more efficiently.  To replace the high half, SSE2 `movq` + `punpcklqdq` or (`movlhps` does the same shuffle).  To replace the low half, `movq` + `movsd xmm,xmm`  SSE2 (`_mm_move_sd` for the merge/blend, not load or store forms) or SSE4 `movq` + `pblendw` (or `blendpd` - extra bypass latency, but doesn't need port 5 on Intel.)  Unfortunately `pblendw` only runs on port 5, until IceLake where it's p15 and `movsd xmm,xmm` is p015.

Comment: what if the value I want to insert at index is "0"? will this help in making a fast/intuitive code?

Comment: Setting the index 1 as zero can be coded as `_mm_and_si128(a, _mm_set_epi32(-1,-1,0,-1));` Thus one instruction with a memory read.
It's also possible, that it will/should be encoded as clearing a register and blending it with an immediate: `_mm_blend_epi16(a, _mm_setzero_si128(), 0x0c);`

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen can you update the answer adding a wrapped function/routine that, giving an "m128i a" and an "int index" set 0 to that index? or do would you a new question for this?

Comment: I added the store_modify_load routine, which is probably the best way to clear an arbitrary index.

Comment: @markzzz: A lower latency (especially for vec->vec, but also idx->vec) option for clearing or setting an arbitrary index might be `mask = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_setr_epi32(0,1,2,3), _mm_set1_epi32(idx));`  and then use that mask with ANDNOT to clear, or AND/ANDNOT/OR to blend in the new value from `_mm_set1_epi32(val)`.  Or with SSE4.1, `blendvps` / `pblendvb` (1 or 2 uops instead of 3 for and/andn/or).  Vector store / scalar store / vector reload saves a lot of uops (front-end throughput) at the expense of a store-fowarding stall https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/03/09/Store-forwarding